# Compare values for the previous rows on leaderboard table, simple query

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, testing, automation

I am trying to compare the pick status of each previous row to ensure the pick status is higher than the previous. The user makes 4 picks and if the pick status is 1 or 2 its added to the pick status total.

The user with the highest total of won_and_looking_good tops the table, but if the user has the same total then their points_player is taken into consideration.

I am basically trying to compare the total_of_won_and_looking_good with the total_of_won_and_looking_good from the previous row, i can seem to figure out how to to do this. This is my code:

test_player_leaderboard_entry() {

```
    int previous_total = 0;

    int size = playerRows.size();


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        //Position
        String position_first_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-position-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Points
        String points_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-points-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Username
        String username_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-player-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Row Number
        Integer row = i + 1;
        Integer total_of_won_and_looking_good = 0;
        //PICKS
        for (int pick_number = 1; pick_number < 5; pick_number++) {
            String pick_status = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/section[2]/section/div/ol/a[" + row + "]/li/div[3]/div[" + pick_number + "]/div")).getAttribute("data-qa-pick-state");
            //System.out.println(pick_status);
            if (Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 2 || Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 1) {
                total_of_won_and_looking_good = total_of_won_and_looking_good + 1;

            }
            }if (i > 0 && total_of_won_and_looking_good >= previous_total) {
            System.out.println("Pick amounts are the same");

        }

        System.out.println("On row number " + row + " we find " + username_player + " in position " + position_first_player + " with " + total_of_won_and_looking_good + " correct picks and " + points_player + " points!");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you keep indentation consistent it is much easier for you and everyone else to understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to test that `total_of_won_and_looking_good` decreases monotonically.

You will need to record the previous value, and if you are not on the first row, compare the new value with the previous value.

You'll need a new local variable:
`int previous_total;` which is declared on the first line of the body of `test_player_leaderboard_entry`.
And after you've calculated the new value, something like:

```
if (i > 0 && total_of_won_and_looking_good > previous_total) {
    // report the error
}
previous_total = total_of_won_and_looking_good;
```

which goes just before your current `System.out.println`.

Comment: I was trying something similar but i kept setting the previous total as the current total, i cant figure out where in the loop to store the previous and the current

Comment: I've made my answer more explicit. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ive tried changing it like above but cant seem to get it working

Comment: You are never setting `previous_total`